# how can i use getLifecycleOwner() method in databinding xml files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-databinding, android-livedata

The class `ViewDataBinding` provides *`setLifecycleOwner()`* and *`setLifecycleOwner()`* 
but when I use it in xml such as

```
android:onClick="@{()->InteractionPresenter.toggleFeedDiss(getLifecycleOwner())}"
```

it will turn out an error like this

> [databinding] {"msg":"Could not find identifier
>   \u0027lifecycleOwner\u0027\n\nCheck that the identifier is spelled
>   correctly, and that no \u003cimport\u003e or \u003cvariable\u003e tags
>   are
>   missing.","file":"/Users/maxz/AndroidStudioProjects/ppjoke/app/src/main/res/layout/layout_feed_interaction.xml","pos":[{"line0":34,"col0":71,"line1":34,"col1":84}]}

so if I want to use LifeCycleOwner in data-binding with lambda, I have to declare another variable like

```
<variable
   name="lifeCycleOwner"
   type="androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner" />
```

then I will use my own variable,it works

but how can I get a lifecycle owner by the first way?

Comment: For the first way, you might need `activity/fragment` variable in xml.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve first approach, You have to pass fragment instance to your layout.

```
<variable
    name="fragment"
    type="androidx.fragment.app.Fragment" />
```

And then use

```
android:onClick="@{()->InteractionPresenter.toggleFeedDiss(fragment.viewLifecycleOwner)}"
```